# How to recreate this overlapping stroke+type effect in Illustrator (Morisowa's "Kikukomi Number" font)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, stroke, glyphs

Please assume I'm a moron, and need some gentle help. So, I really like this ascending-ordered, overlapping type:

[image]

I understand it to be a feature of a font by Morisowa (https://twitter.com/hamko1114/status/1296700184827531265), but I'd like to implement the laying & overlapping in another font. Is there a proper name for this? Can this be done in Glyphs? Huge thanks to anyone who can push me in the right direction :))

Comment: You can not do this in a font itself it relies on a stroke feature of the font rendering engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't see this as somehow manipulating the font itself, but rather as treating the characters as any other kind of vector graphics. This is actually quite easy to make if you can live with the text being expanded and no longer being editable.

First of all you need to decrease the distance between the characters. Open the *Character* panel, select the text and decrease the *tracking* until the characters have the wanted overlap (hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> to increment 10 for each click).

[image]

Just adding a white stroke to the text won't give the desired effect. All the strokes are rendered on top of all the fills:

[image]

But if you select the text object and use *Object > Expand*, the individual characters are turned into ordinary separate vector objects, and they are layered in ascending order by default:

[image]

Make sure to enter the *Stroke* panel and set *Align Stroke* to *Align Stroke to Outside*. This will make the whole original character visible and the white stroke will only hide part of the underlying letters.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks amigo!

Comment: @FloydGondolli, you are welcome! And welcome to the site. Remember to *accept* the answer if it works for you, so it gets marked as accepted and I get my reputation points . Or wait a while and see if a better answer comes along.

Comment: Haha, thank you! You answer does the trick. Any idea if this is possible via CSS?

Comment: @FloydGondolli, not in any obvious way I'm afraid. Just tried. The `text-stroke` property has the same problem as before expanding the text in Illustrator (and isn't widely supported). And the `text-shadow` property adds shadow to the text as a whole, not to the individual letters. There might be some workaround. Perhaps if the letters are somehow in separate containers?

Comment: Something to think about! Thanks again :)